# Why is Trial of Ansible Tower install failing on CentOS7 due to rabbitmq service being in a running state (not restarted, started)?

Tags: installation, ansible

Getting the following error when installing a trial version of Ansible Tower on CentOS7:

```
TASK [rabbitmq : start and enable the rabbitmq service] **********************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "value of state must be one of: reloaded, restarted, started, stopped, got: running"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by commenting that check out in the main.yml for rabbit and then restarting the rabbitmq-server service with systemctl during the check where it makes sure its running with a second window.

I dont know why it does that but this work-around fixed it for me.